# WhatsApp profile pics of some contacted added but now have disappeared

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Some of my contacts didn’t add a pic on their WhatsApp profile. As I had pics of them, I added their pics from my phone contact list, and they were automatically transferred to my WhatsApp.

But suddenly, some of these pics disappeared on WhatsApp. I still can see them in my phone contact list, but not on WhatsApp anymore. And I still can see their last seen, so I believe they didn’t block me...

What could be going on??

Comment: You are facing this for one (or a group of) user, or for all users you added pics? If it is for all, it might be related to some update on the app's behavior (It seems odd to me that someone else is able to choose a picture of me - even if it is for his own phone - for a social app). Also, another thing, if a user blocks you, his/her pic is removed. Wouldn't this be the problem?

Comment: For all the ones I’ve added pics in my phone contact list... But I think they didn’t block me, because although the pics I’ve added for them disappeared, I still can see the last time they were online.